# How to extract values from a text CLOB field in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, substr, clob

I have an SQL table column (BINARYTEXT) populated with a [CLOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_large_object). Within this CLOB is a number of attributes, e.g.,

```
CE.EffDate="20140106";
CE.CCY="EUR";
CE.TransactionType="STANDARDEUROPEAN";
CE.CAL="LON";
```

I need to extract only the value of the CE.TransactionType attribute contained between the double quotes so 'STANDARDEUROPEAN'. Note that the CLOB does not contain XML and only contains attributes as above with no start or end tags.

I have worked out how to do this using the REGEXP_SUBSTR function when I specify the string in the command:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('CE.TransactionType="STANDARDEUROPEAN"', '="[^"]+') transtype
from DUAL
```

which returns: ="STANDARDEUROPEAN

I am unable to manipulate this into using the CLOB as the string. This does not work:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(BINARYTEXT,'CE.TransactionType="STANDARDEUROPEAN"', '="[^"]+')  transtype
from DUAL
```

This comes up with a blank integer error, although I am unsure why it is expecting an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DBMS_LOB package to extract the string.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(DBMS_LOB.substr(BINARYTEXT,3000) ,'CE.TransactionType="STANDARDEUROPEAN"', '="[^"]+')  transtype
FROM YOURTABLENAME
```

The only thing you might have problems with is the buffer size, which is restricted to 32767 bytes (it's set to 3000 in my example). If your data is bigger than this, then you'd need to query it in chunks. See the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i999349)

If you need to change the TransactionType you're searching for, you should probably create a function which takes that part of the string as a parameter and build the SQL content dynamically.

Comment: Also note that the value within the double quotes will change so I will need to search on the CE.TransactionType=" as 'STANDARDEUROPEAN' is only an example as 'STANDARDNORTHAMERICAN' is another possibility. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
select BINARYTEXT from your_table
where regexp_like(dat,'^(\CE.TransactionType=)?"[^"]+"?;$');
```

Comment: Hi Sai. Is this taking into account the fact that the information is in a single column CLOB for each record?

E.g. 
    Record 1   CLOB
    Record 2   CLOB
    Record 3   CLOB

Also I am looking only for the value of TransactionType ignoring all other rows of data in the CLOB. The SQL you provided only searches on the double quote and not on the actual text I require. Thanks

Comment: so u want o/p like CE.TransactionType="STANDARDEUROPEAN" ?

Comment: Yes for the first part as CE.TransactionType=" never changes but the value between the quotes is what changes and is what I want to return using the query.

Comment: hope my edit helps u.. the query will return nulls for unmatched rows

Comment: I think there is an issue with the matching as all rows are coming up blank.

Comment: Hi Sai. This seems to be running but still returns zero rows. The actual data in the CLOB contains a semi colon after the last double quote. Does this need to be added to the expression to match the end of the line? e.g. data in CLOB is: CE.TransactionType="STANDARDEUROPEAN";

Comment: sry..didn't get u.. you want to say at the time of data insert if you entered like CE.TransactionType="STANDARDEUROPEAN"; then you should mention ; in the expression..

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below SQL:

```
select substr ( REGEXP_SUBSTR(to_clob ('CE.EffDate="20140106"; CE.CCY="EUR";CE.TransactionType="STANDARDEUROPEAN";CE.CAL="LON";'), '="[^"]+', 1,3), 3)  transtype from DUAL
```

Comment: Re *"You can try"*: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70595130/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

If your db does not have REGEXP, you can use the DBMS_LOB package (as [mentioned by StevieG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955824/how-to-extract-values-from-a-text-clob-field-in-sql/20956231#20956231)). Here is SQL using just the DBMS_LOB... I used the semicolon as a delimiter as it is in your CLOB string in the question.

```
WITH
    table_test As
        (
            Select
              TO_CLOB('... ... ...
                       Some other text within the CLOB field
                       ...
                       CE.EffDate="20140106";
                       CE.CCY="EUR";
                       CE.TransactionType="STANDARDEUROPEAN";
                       CE.CAL="LON";
                       and yet some more text;
                       and more ...
                       ... ... ...
                    ') "BINARYTEXT"
            From Dual
        )
Select
    DBMS_LOB.SubStr(
                      DBMS_LOB.SubStr(BINARYTEXT, 100, InStr(BINARYTEXT, 'CE.TransactionType=') + Length('CE.TransactionType=')+1),
                      InStr(DBMS_LOB.SubStr(BINARYTEXT, 100, InStr(BINARYTEXT, 'CE.TransactionType=') + Length('CE.TransactionType=')+1), ';')-2,
                      1

                    ) "TRANSACTION_TYPE"
From
    table_test
--
-- Result:
--
-- TRANSACTION_TYPE
-- STANDARDEUROPEAN
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` function expects a string as its first argument, and the `BINARYTEXT` column is a CLOB. To fix this, you can use the `DBMS_LOB` package to convert the CLOB to a string. The following query will work:

```sql
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(DBMS_LOB.substr(BINARYTEXT, 3000), 'CE.TransactionType="STANDARDEUROPEAN"', '="[^"]+')  transtype 
from DUAL
```

This query will first use the `DBMS_LOB.substr` function to convert the `BINARYTEXT` column to a string with a maximum length of 3000 characters. It will then use the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` function to extract the value of the `CE.TransactionType` attribute from the string. The result will be a string containing the value of the `CE.TransactionType` attribute, or `NULL` if the attribute is not found.

Here is an example of the output of this query:

```sql
| transtype |
|----------|
| STANDARDEUROPEAN |
```

Comment: [Three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76697548) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76694777/how-do-you-know-if-a-class-can-not-create-an-instant-object-in-java-without-read/76695382#76695382) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76695072/is-it-possible-to-check-for-content-encoding-header-programmatically/76695257#76695257) posted within the same about 48 hours were likely generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned), so this one was probably generated by ChatGPT as well.