# Is it possible to check for content-encoding header programmatically?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

We are developing a saas web product and need to bill the customer for data transfer usage. Tomcat server is enabled with compression and the responses above 2048 bytes would be encoded, so would it be possible to check for Content-Encoding header programmatically ?

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it is possible to check for the Content-Encoding header programmatically in your web application. The Content-Encoding header is included in the HTTP response headers and indicates whether the response has been encoded, such as with compression.

To check for the Content-Encoding header programmatically, you can access the response headers in your web application code. The specific implementation depends on the programming language or framework you are using.

In Java with Tomcat, you can use the Servlet API to access the response headers. Here's an example using Java Servlets:

```java
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Get the Content-Encoding header from the response
    String contentEncoding = response.getHeader("Content-Encoding");
    
    // Check if the Content-Encoding header is present and if it indicates compression
    if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.contains("gzip")) {
        // Content is compressed
        // You can handle billing for data transfer usage accordingly
    } else {
        // Content is not compressed
        // Handle billing for data transfer usage accordingly
    }
}
```

This code retrieves the Content-Encoding header from the response and checks if it contains the value "gzip" to determine if the response is compressed. You can then handle the billing for data transfer usage based on this information.

Remember to adapt the code to your specific programming language or framework if you are not using Java with Tomcat.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT